# Collate Multiple Columns in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm working in a tracker where the rows are organized by project. The tracker includes columns identifying the lead and support managers for the projects, along with the # of hours per week that the manager spends on the project:

***Project Tracker table***
[image: Project Tracker table]

I'm trying to create a pivot table that lists each manager, the total number of hours per week worked on all projects, and the total number of projects supported:

***desired output***
[image: desired output]

I'm having trouble building relationships that allow me to sum the values in columns C, E, and G and filter by the Manager Name. I don't think I can build lookup or index/match formulas because a manager can be listed multiple times in the same column.

I'm having trouble building relationships that allow me to sum the values in columns C, E, and G and filter by the Manager Name. I don't think I can build lookup or index/match formulas because a manager can be listed multiple times in the same column.

Sample data file:

[Example Project Tracker](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uWv2yrSzZRoMcriKYWQVY0N6GZInmxgA/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=103541210800646857642&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: You can use `Power Query` (available in Excel 2010 and later) to unpivot the `Project Tracker` table into the pairs of "Manager/ hours" and then generate your summary that way.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun I wanted to give the new [`GROUPBY()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/groupby-function-5e08ae8c-6800-4b72-b623-c41773611505) function a try:

[image]

Formula in `I1`:

```
=LET(x,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(B2:G6),2),y,TAKE(x,,1),z,GROUPBY(y,DROP(x,,1),SUM,,0,,y<>"N/A"),VSTACK({"Manager","Hours Per Week","Projects Supported"},HSTACK(z,COUNTIF(B2:G6,TAKE(z,,1)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, you could try as well. Posting the alternative because for now both **[GROUPBY](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/groupby-function-5e08ae8c-6800-4b72-b623-c41773611505)** & **[PIVOTBY](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pivotby-function-de86516a-90ad-4ced-8522-3a25fac389cf)** functions are in **`Beta Channel`** for **`Windows Excel`** and **`Mac Excel`**

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(DROP(A2:G6,,1)),2),
     φ, FILTER(α, TAKE(α,,1)<>"N/A"),
     δ, TAKE(φ,,1),
     ε, MMULT(N(δ=TOROW(δ)),DROP(φ,,1)),
     Ψ, MMULT(N(δ=TOROW(δ)),DROP(φ,,1)^0),
     VSTACK({"Manager","Hours Per Week","Projects Supported"},
     SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(δ, ε, Ψ)))))
```

---

This can also be accomplished quickly and easily using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>. To achieve this using the said procedure, follow these simple steps using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd> window `UI`:

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Project Name"}),
    #"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns" = Table.Unpivot(#"Removed Columns", {"Lead Manager", "Lead Weekly Hours", "First Support Manager", "First Support Weekly Hours", "Second Support Manager", "Second Support Weekly Hours"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Unpivoted Only Selected Columns", "Hours", each if Text.Contains([Attribute], "Hours") then [Value] else null),
    #"Filled Up" = Table.FillUp(#"Added Conditional Column",{"Hours"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Up", each not Text.Contains([Attribute], "Hours")),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Removed Columns1", each [Value] <> null and [Value] <> ""and [Value] <> "N/A"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows1", {"Value"}, {{"Manager", each _, type table [Value=text, Hours=number]}, {"Hours Per Week", each List.Sum([Hours]), type number}, {"Projects Supported", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Manager"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns2",{{"Value", "Manager"}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Renamed Columns",{{"Manager", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

Here is another Power Query algorithm which, if you have a large database, should execute more rapidly than others I have tested.

In addition, it is agnostic as to the actual column names, requiring that they only be in the order of:

```
|Project|Manager|Hours|Manager|Hours|...|
```

***Note:*** *If a Manager might be listed twice on the same **ROW** (i.e: two roles in a single project), we will need to modify the code to take that into account*

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***Your Data***
[image]

***M Code***

```
let

//change next lines to reflect actual table source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table20"]}[Content],

    cn = List.Buffer(Table.ColumnNames(Source)),
    managers = List.Buffer(List.Alternate(cn,1,1)),
    hours = List.Buffer(List.RemoveFirstN(List.Alternate(cn,1,1,1),1)),

    #"Set Data Types" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, 
        {{cn{0}, type text}} 
        & List.Transform(managers, each {_, type text}) 
        & List.Transform(hours, each {_, type number})),

    #"Split Tables" = Table.Combine(List.Generate(
        ()=>[t=Table.FromColumns(
                Table.ToColumns(
                    Table.SelectColumns(#"Set Data Types",{cn{0},managers{0},hours{0}})),
                    type table[Project=text, Manager=text, Hours=number]), idx=0],
        each [idx]<List.Count(managers),
        each [t=Table.FromColumns(
                Table.ToColumns(
                    Table.SelectColumns(#"Set Data Types",{cn{0},managers{[idx]+1},hours{[idx]+1}})),
                    type table[Project=text, Manager=text, Hours=number]),
                     idx=[idx]+1],
        each [t]
    )),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Split Tables", each ([Manager] <> "N/A")),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Manager"}, {
        {"Hours Per Week", each List.Sum([Hours]), type number}, 
        {"Projects Supported", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

***Results***
[image]